# Linux equivalent for VirtualProtectEx?

Tags: linux, jit, data-execution-prevention

I am doing some simple JITing, and use [VirtualProtectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366899%28VS.85%29.aspx) under Windows to mark pages as executable.
What would be the equivalent of that under Linux, and preferably, other POSIX/Unix-like OSes too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [mprotect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect) and probably also [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap).  Note that, unlike with Windows, there is no way for process A to change process B's memory map (short of horrible tricks with [ptrace](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace)).

Comment: ...and keep in mind that some hardened kernels will prevent you from setting both write and execute permissions at the same time (`PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC`).

Comment: Yeah, also processes can change each others' memory by mmap'ing parts of their /proc/pid/mem

Comment: MarkR: Processes can *write to each others' memory* with /proc/pid/mem or various other standard APIs (`shm*`, `mmap` with `MAP_SHARED`, etc) but that's not what I meant by "can't change another process's memory map".  `VirtualProtectEx` and its friends let you change page permissions or allocate/deallocate memory in the address space of another process; that's what you can't do without dirty tricks on Unix.  (Oddly, unless I missed something, Windows doesn't let you do a `MapViewOfFile(Ex)` operation on anyone but yourself.)